# Webdriver & .Net - TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData() does not clear TimeZone cache

Tags: .net, caching, webdriver, timezone

The application I'm automating requires a unique reference number every time I fill out a form, and I do this in most of my tests using `DateTime.Now` as my unique reference number:

```
public static string Today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

When I run these tests via Visual Studio for each test I get a unique DateTime.Now; which is correct behaviour. But when I run the same tests via Nunit GUI or TeamCity CI the `DateTime.Now` is cached from the first test run and therefore all tests there after fail.

I attempted to use `TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData()` in my TearDown section after each test run:

```
    [AfterScenario]
    public static void TearDown()
    {
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
        TimeZoneInfo.ClearCachedData();
        driver.Quit();
    }
```

But this does not clear the cache when I run via Nunit GUI or TeamCity. I have tried using DateTime.UtcNow and also moving the ClearCachedData code in the setup section, but neither of these options work for me.

Has anyone overcome this issue before?

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you run a selection of tests using Visual Studio?

Comment: Solution:
.
I had defined the string as Static, removing this solves the problem:

public string Today = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

Comment: ClearCachedData has entirely different purpose.  You can remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the static field will be initialized once and then keep it's value.

You have since removed the `static` part, you didn't need to necessarily do that. Just make it a property so that it's value is generated on every access:

```
public static string Today { get { return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); } }
```

NUnit's GUI and TeamCity will launch the whole suite in one thread. So the static field you had originally will literally be loaded only once and keep it's value.

Comment: Great description Arran, thanks for that. As I didn't fully understand that Nunit GUI and TC will launch the whole suite in one thread.

Comment: @BennyMeade - `static` isn't per thread, it's per *process*.  All instances and all threads share the same values.  There is `[ThreadStatic]` if you really want a per-thread value.